# Uncommenting lines in php.ini file on 000webhost

Tags: php, php.ini, soap

I recently asked a question about a php error

after playing with the php.ini file I found that after commenting

> extension=php_soap.dll

I got the same error as I did on the internet

so I relized that line on 000webhost's php.ini file must be commented

Other than hack into 000webhost and change the file I don't know how to uncomment a line

all I need to do is change

> ;extension=php_soap.dll

to

> extension=php_soap.dll

I cannot use a php function because this only allows you to change an existing line not one that is commented

what am I to do

I tried copying php_soap.dll and putting in the same directory as my php file but I still got the same error

I don't know what to do

### thanks

Comment: Have you tried *asking them*? You never know, they might oblige...

Answer (score 1):

If 000webhost haven't enabled/installed the php_soap extension, there's probably sod all you can do about it.

Have you tried

```
dl("php_soap.dll");
```

to load the module at run-time?

Don't try and hack in and change it on their server config, they'll be pissed off, and you'll be breaking the law.

You might also try and find a pure PHP SOAP library, that doesn't rely on the php_soap extension..  Or find a non-crap webhost that supports it, or get a VPS server instead of shared hosting, then you'll have full control over the server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Talk to your webhost.  If you start trying to do this yourself, you may end up violating your TOS with them.  Depending on the host, they might enable this if you ask.  If they won't enable it, you would have to choose another host, or avoid using that module.